# Wpf xamlreader load xaml with custom elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamlreader

I got a canvas with custom elements, similar to texboxes and shapes.

```
<Canvas Name="SomeCanvas" >
    <TextBox_Element   Canvas.Left="400" Canvas.Top="200" Height="50" Name="s3" Background="#57FF3ACB"  />
</Canvas>
```

Which im saving to a file with:

```
SerializeToXML(filename, SomeCanvas);
```

Later I´m trying to load that file and convert ist back to the original canvas with:

```
FileStream fs = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Canvas savedCanvas = XamlReader.Load(fs) as Canvas;
```

The last method throws a XamlParseException:

> No matching constructor found on type '...TextBox_Element'. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.'

Does anybody know how to restore the canvas the way it was from the file? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a parameterless constructor in your custom class? If not, try  this:

```
public class TextBox_Element{

    public TextBox_Element(double x, double y){
        // code
    }
    public TextBox_Element(){
        // emptyness
    }
}
```

That worked for me, i hope itsolves your problem too!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a parameterless constructor in your `TextBox_Element`.

**XamlReader.Load** by default will **always** look for an empty constructor while if it has a required parameters you'll have to add more work.

According to [Max Galkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335900/using-xamlreader-for-controls-that-does-not-have-a-default-constructor)

> It's a "feature" of the XAML language, it is declarative and doesn't know anything about constructors. People use [ObjectDataProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335900/using-xamlreader-for-controls-that-does-not-have-a-default-constructor) in XAML to "translate" and wrap instances of classes that do not have a parameterless constructor (it's [also useful for data binding][2]).

In your case it'll be approximately like this:

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="TextBox_Element">
    <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        <x:Double>400</x:Double>
        <x:Double>200</x:Double>
    </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>


var textBoxElem = (TextBox_Element) ((ObjectDataProvider)XamlReader.Parse(xamlStr)).Data;
```

Assuming your `TextBox_Element` constructor looks like this

```
public class TextBox_Element
{
  public TextBox_Element(double left, double top)
  {
    // do whatever
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the file it saved to did not contain the information required on your custom element? Just as if you save a textbox, the XamlReader needs to have the xmlns references to be able to read it.